# Google PubSub Pull timeout with .setReturnImmediately(false)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Is it possible to set a custom timeout for pull mode with setReturnImmediately(false)?

The current timeout is 20 seconds.

Using Google Cloud Services API client Java library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    HttpRequestInitializer customInit = (request) -> {
            credential.initialize(request);
            request.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            request.setReadTimeout(3000);
    };


    Pubsub.Builder builder = new Pubsub.Builder(TRANSPORT, 
                                                JSON_FACTORY, 
                                                credential)
            .setHttpRequestInitializer(customInit)
            .setApplicationName("app-name");
```